# FastReport combine reports into one

Tags: fastreport

I am using FastReport4. 
I have several instances of reports (tfrxReport) on my datamodule form.

They all show only one page, and I would like to combine those different reports into one, so that when I click once, I get all those reports one after another.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
frxReport1.PrepareReport;
frxReport2.PrepareReport;
frxReport1.PreviewPages.AddFrom(frxReport2);
frxReport1.ShowPreparedReport;
```

Comment: Great! That's it! Thank you for your help!